# Centering a video inside a DIV

Tags: html, css, video

How can I center this video inside the DIV in which it is contained?

```css
.courses-container {
display: table-cell;
width: 100%;
background-color: #00ffd0;
}

.courses-col{
float: left;
width: 50%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
.courses-col {
float: left;
width: 100%;
}
}

center {
text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="courses-container">
<div class="courses-col">
<br>
<video class="center" width="80%" autoplay controls loop>
<source src="Video URL" type="video/mp4">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
<br><br>
</div>

<div class="courses-col">
<br>
<p>Text</p>
<br>
</div>
</div>
```

I just need to be able to center the video that displays to the left of the text. How would I do this given that it is in a DIV?

Answer (score 0):

Just add:

```
video.center {
margin: auto;
display: block;
```

}